Sci-fi movie about a woman alone on a spaceship with an AI
I remember this movie from 2010-2019ish.
If I recall correctly, the main character was a woman who was alone on a spaceship with an AI. I'm pretty sure the big reveal was that the whole movie was some big test or simulation to see how well she could save humanity (there was a time limit?) and, at the very end, there was a video which she had recorded for herself, explaining everything (indicating that she had her memory erased).

Is this Oxygen (2021)...?

A woman wakes in a cryogenic chamber with no recollection of how she got there. As she's running out of oxygen, she must rebuild her memory to find a way out of her nightmare.

A woman wakes up in a cryogenic pod with approximately ninety minutes worth of oxygen remaining. She doesn't know who she is, why she's in the pod, or where it is (she can't see outside), but initially assumes it's somewhere on Earth.



The pod contains an AI named M.I.L.O. (Medical Interface Liaison Officer) which is monitoring her vital signs. She can converse with it and it grants her access to a database containing news articles, images and videos, but it won't open the pod without an authorisation code, and when she asks it what her name is, it identifies her simply as Omicron 267. After asking M.I.L.O. to run a DNA scan on her, it informs her that her DNA matches that of Elizabeth Hansen, a doctor specialising in cryogenics. Viewing images of Hansen and her husband triggers some fragmented memories and more surface as the film progresses, but, for now, most of her life remains a blank to her.
It subsequently transpires that she's not on Earth after all, but on an automated colony ship transporting ten thousand people in pods like hers to a planet in another star system. The other passengers are asleep, as she's meant to be; she awoke due to a malfunction caused by an asteroid collision. The ship's purpose is to ensure the continued existence of the human race, since a deadly virus has broken out on Earth and is expected to kill everyone there within two generations.



After viewing a video of a presentation on memory-transference technology given by an elderly Elizabeth Hansen, Omicron 267 also realises she's a clone of Hansen, implanted with her memories. The other passengers on the ship are clones with implanted memories as well, created in a sterile environment and kept insulated in order to prevent them from contracting the virus and carrying it to the other planet.
This is a French-language film, but you didn't say which language you watched it in and you may have seen a dubbed version. If it is the right film, then M.I.L.O.'s periodic updates on how much oxygen Omicron 267 has remaining would equate to the time limit you mentioned.




At first glance at the question's title, I immediately thought of this exact film, vaguely recalling that I watched it a few years back on Netflix. I'm glad I'm not the only one who remembers it. However, I feel like the specifics of the description regarding a video recording and a test/simulation don't seem to align with my recollection of the film. The struggle could be perceived as a form of test in one's memories, given the general theme, but the lack of mention of the other character, which seemed significant in the second half, makes me doubtful. Also, not really much of a spaceship. :/

Continuum (2013) starring Melanie merkosky. The female lead wakes up alone on the spaceship, no memory, just the AI, later a male character comes into it. As I recall, yes she finds the truth from a video she made. Apparently film is pieced together from a web series

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is the reveal that it's all been a simulation?

I'll need to watch it again (it's on YouTube channel of the production company), but that would definitely be a spoiler! https://www.youtube.com/user/ContinuumTheSeries

This really reminded me of Katee Sackhoff in Another Life if I've remembered it correctly (which is only somewhat likely).  It's also a Netflix series rather than a film.
https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8369840/

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you explain how this movie matches the details of the question?  Is there a test?  Is the goal to save humanity?  Is an explanatory video given to the hero at the end?

But in that series, she's not aline on the ship. Also, everything is quite what it seems, she really is on a space travel (a journey to revisit countless scifi tropes taken over from other franchises).
